# Unable to cast object of type 'System.Random' to type 'System.IConvertible'

Tags: c#, .net

I am writing a small Heads or Tails program using the Random function and receive an Unable to cast object of type 'System.Random' to type 'System.IConvertible' message and am not sure why. Can someone shed a little light. Thanks.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Random rNum = new Random();
    rNum.Next(2, 47);


    int rrNum = Convert.ToInt32(rNum);

    string result;
    result = (rrNum % 2 == 0) ? "Heads" : "Tails";
    lblResult.Text = result;

}
```

Comment: A piece of advice for the future: whenever you receive an error message in C#, check the line it occurred on, make sure you have the correct parameter types / variable types / etc, check for inner exceptions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`Next`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2dx6wyd4.aspx) on random *returns* an integer. So the correct code is:

```
Random rNum = new Random();
int rrNum = rNum.Next(2, 47);
```

So from there there is no need to convert `rNum` to an integer.

```
Random rNum = new Random();
int rrNum = rNum.Next(2, 47);
string result = (rrNum % 2 == 0) ? "Heads" : "Tails";
lblResult.Text = result;
```

Comment: +1 The only answer that actually _looked_ at the context of the code. It seems indeed unlikely that the OP really intended to convert an object of type Random ;)

Answer (score 1):

That's because `Convert.ToIn32()` demands the passed object implements `IConvertible`.

To retrieve a random number, you need to call the `Random.Next()` method, like so:

```
Random rNum = new Random(); 
int YourRandomNumber = rNum.Next(2, 47);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to assign the value returned from `rNum.Next(2,47)` to a variable like so:

```
int rrNum = rNum.Next(2,47);
```

`rNum` is of type `Random`. You cannot convert that type to an `int`.

`rNum.Next(2,47)` returns the `int` that you want. If you look at the documentation for [Random.Next](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2dx6wyd4.aspx) you will see that its type signature is:

```
public virtual int Next(int minValue, int maxValue);
```

The `int` in `public virtual int` is the return type of the method. You can use this information to determine what type of variable you need to store what is returned from the call to `Next`.

Answer (score -2):

Exactly as the error message states, you cant convert an instance of System.Random to in this case an Int.